# how to list all TABLES(not records) of a database in a drop down list MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am creating an onlineshop, where the user is going to add a new record, by typing the title, description, price and image, but I also want to put a dropdown list of all my TABLES names for the user to select them as a category for adding the product.
The details of my database are:
db name = onlineshop

connect.php

```
<?php    
    // Try to connect to MySQL
    $connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '') or die('Sorry could not connect to     database');
    // Check connect and return error if failed
 $use_db = mysql_select_db('onlineshop');
$create_db = "CREATE DATABASE onlineshop";
if(!$use_db) {
    echo mysql_error();
    mysql_query($create_db);
    mysql_select_db('onlineshop');
}
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','root', '');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

// Create database
$sql="CREATE DATABASE onlineshop";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  echo "Database my_db created successfully";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
  }

//main table
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE mens( '.
       'id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, '.
       'title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, '.
       'description  VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, '.
       'price   FLOAT NOT NULL, '.
       'image varchar(200),'.
       'image_small varchar(200),'.
       'primary key ( id ))';

//copy attributes of the main table
$sql2= 'CREATE TABLE women AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql3= 'CREATE TABLE kids AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql4= 'CREATE TABLE infants AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql5= 'CREATE TABLE baby_books AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql6= 'CREATE TABLE garden AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql7= 'CREATE TABLE comics AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql8= 'CREATE TABLE cooking AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql9= 'CREATE TABLE desktop AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql10= 'CREATE TABLE laptop AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql11= 'CREATE TABLE mobile AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql12= 'CREATE TABLE misc AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql13= 'CREATE TABLE moviestv AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql14= 'CREATE TABLE music AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';
$sql15= 'CREATE TABLE games AS ( SELECT * FROM mens where 1=2)';



$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $connect );
$retval2 = mysql_query($sql2, $connect);
$retval3 = mysql_query($sql3, $connect);
$retval4 = mysql_query($sql4, $connect);
$retval5 = mysql_query($sql5, $connect);
$retval6 = mysql_query($sql6, $connect);
$retval7 = mysql_query($sql7, $connect);
$retval8 = mysql_query($sql8, $connect);
$retval9 = mysql_query($sql9, $connect);
$retval10 = mysql_query($sql10, $connect);
$retval11 = mysql_query($sql11, $connect);
$retval12 = mysql_query($sql12, $connect);
$retval13 = mysql_query($sql13, $connect);
$retval14 = mysql_query($sql14, $connect);
$retval15 = mysql_query($sql15, $connect);
?>
```

dropdown.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect('localhost','root', '') or die('Sorry could not connect to database');

function runSQL($sql)
{
    $mysqlConnection = getConnection();
    $ResultSet = $mysqlConnection->query($sql);

    return $ResultSet;
}

function getTableList()
{
    $sql = "SHOW TABLES";
    $ResultSet = runSQL($sql);

    if(!$ResultSet)
    {
        echo "Table list not found";
    }

    return $ResultSet;
}
?>
```

index contains a form as well as a function that i found online that calls the dropdown.php

index.html

```
   <form action="insert.php" method="post">
<br>
<div><label for="title">Title: </label><input type="text" name="title"/></div>
<div><label for="description">Desc: </label><input type="text" name="description"/></div>
<div><label for="price">Price: </label><input type="text" name="price" /></div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>



<form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
Upload your image <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
</form>
<div id='preview'>
</div> 


<?php
include_once 'dropdown.php';
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <select name="Tables" id="ddTables">
            <?php
                $tableResults = getTableList();
                if($tableResults)
                {
                    if($tableResults->rowCount() > 0)
                    {
                        $tables = $tableResults->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
                        foreach($tables as $table)
                        {
                            $name = $table[0];
                            echo '<option value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>';
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '<option value="0">No Data</option>';
                }
            ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" id="tableSubmit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
```

All i get is an empty dropdown list

I really new into PHP, so please let me know of ANY suggestions for my database, as well as if you suggest me to include a script.

i pretty sure that the problem is that the getTablesList() function in the index.html is not returning anything.

open to any suggestions

Comment: Are we talking about a lot of a tables.? It may not to be a bad idea to do it manually,  just in case in the future you add a table you don't want to show it in the list.

Comment: what do you mean 'manually'?

Comment: Manually as in add them yourself to the drop down list.

Comment: and will I match them with my database tables?

Comment: Yes. Unless you will be adding new ones all the time.

Comment: no I want these will be my tables

Comment: Ok ill post the the link to show table from mysql from PHP.NET and example example maybe you can use it or some pats of it in your script

Comment: is there a way to remove the submit button and include ONE submit button for both 3 forms? for the text input, image and the dropdown list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example on how to list Tables from PHP.NET

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php

**dropdown.php**

```
    <?php
    $dbname = 'mysql_dbname';
    
    if (!mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')) {
        echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
        exit;
    }
    
    $sql = "SHOW TABLES FROM $dbname";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    
    if (!$result) {
        echo "DB Error, could not list tables\n";
        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
    
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {


   $tables .='<option value="{$row[0]}">{$row[0]}</option>';
       
    }
    
    mysql_free_result($result);
    ?>
```

in **index.html**

```
<?php 

include_once 'dropdown.php'; 

?> 
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
<select name="Tables" id="ddTables">
<?php 

echo $tables;

?>
     </select>
     <input type="submit" id="tableSubmit" value="Submit"/>
     </form>
```

Comment: and the form(HTML) I am going to use for the drop down?

Comment: I can see the tables now but in a text format, I need to load the php function above into an HTML form (drop down list)

Comment: Ok one sec let me show you another way it can be done with your code

Comment: the function above does work I can see my tables listed. With that way I believe if I create a form with a dropdown list loading the php file it ll work. I just need to figure out the loop used in the form

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: tables in ...../dropdown.php on line 21

I get the list, but the names on the drop down list are {$row[0]}

Comment: Well i recoded the code to produce the drop-down list first end echo it out as as tables. But you are submitting to the same page so im not sure if the submit from the tables it going to work. Not sure. And you are using PDO to connect to the DB to perform actions. Anyway from the example i did were you populate the Tables first in a variable, its ok

Comment: do you know why it displays the tables as  {$row[0]}? is it a syntax error?

Comment: sorry try this $row[0]  --  take out the {}

Comment: can I modify the code in order to make the list options match my table names?

Comment: whats the output your getting now then,,, whats not matching

Comment: $tables .='<option value="$row[0]">$row[0]</option>';   
i still see the drop list options as $row[0] now

Comment: so in the drop down list you get  $row[0] as the options instead of table name?

Comment: If thats then case do this  -- $tables .="<option value='$row[0]'>$row[0]</option>";

Comment: thats great it works! but I still get an Undentified variable tables at that line. do you know why?

Comment: whats showing that error?. If i think right its because $tables concantinates  to itself, so just above this  ---   while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) { -- add this ---  $tables = '';

Comment: respect, really glad we sorted this out

Comment: I have asked another question, so if you please looking forward to work with you again if you have the time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to run `SHOW TABLES', try

```
SELECT *
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema = 'onlineshop';
```

You are going to want to use more clauses within the WHERE clause to limit the actuals tables that are shown.

Comment: what kind of error? This is probably the best way to do it

Answer (score 0):

If you're pre-PHP 5.5.0, you can use the `mysql_list_tables` function (Docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-tables.php)

If you're using PHP 5.5.0 or later, I'm not sure if there's a similar method for `mysqli` objects or not, but you can also modify your query from `"SHOW TABLES"` to `"SHOW TABLES FROM $db_name"`

Comment: I get a 'No Data' field into my drop down list when I do both methods. What might be the problem?

The No data result is listed in the statement at the index.html getTableList() function

Comment: The `rowCount` method doesn't necessarily return what you expect it to ([see here](http://ca2.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)); in some databases it will, but not all. Try using [`num_rows`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) instead

Comment: is there a way to modifing the php code of the index function? i am not really happy with it i just want to make it simplier

Comment: Someone with more experience dealing with PDO objects could guide you better here, but it seems that there's either a problem with using those methods to get the size of a result set, or a problem with the dataset you're querying. If you can verify that you're creating all of your tables properly, then it would suggest you're going about getting the size of the result set incorrectly. I can't help much more with that, unfortunately; I've never personally dealt with a case where I had to know that ahead of time